# Magento 1.9 Edit Attribute issue - Unique values

Tags: magento, attributes

I'm trying to edit the attribute "description" in the Admin panel.  I need the "unique value required" to be set as "no".  However the current setting is set as YES and grayed out so I cannot change it.

Is there some way that I can change this so that the "description" attribute does not have to be a unique value?

Comment: if you want to change this field to yes you can check the table eav_attribute attribte_id is 72 for description there is a field is_unique you can change there or you can change using php script thanks

Comment: Got it!  Thank you for the clear explanation!